# Can kubernetes-helm templates use variables?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a generic template for a k8s resource that I want to expand n times (if you are curious, it is so that I can create n members of a mongo cluster and they are using the statefulset resource so that each member has a stable network name).

Obviously I need different values each time through the loop.  I am looping over a series of indices generated by the Sprig "until" function.  But the $index for the loop does not get set in the "." namespace.  So I am unable to refer the the current iteration inside of my defined template in my _helpers.tpl file.

here is an example template w/full k8s resource yaml (I'm abbreviating most of it):

```
{{- define "mytest" -}} 
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
  abbreviated...
  containers:
  - name: mongod-$index
  abbreviated...
{{- end -}}
```

caller:

```
{{ range $index, $e := until .Values.mongod_count }}
    {{include "mytest" .}}
{{ end}}
```

I just get: undefined variable "$index"

I have tried with blocks too, like this in my (caller) template:

```
{{ $foo := "somevalue" }}
{{ define "my_extra_labels" }} bla {{ .Values.test }}_{{$foo}}{{end}}
{{ template "mytest" . }}
```

And this in my _helpers.tpl

```
{{/* Test stuff */}} 
{{- define "mytest" -}}
hello: world_how_are_{{ block "my_extra_labels" . }}{{ end }}
{{- end -}}
```

The variable $foo is not defined in the "define" body.

This template scoping feels so restrictive that at this point I can't see how to use it to solve my current scenario.

Is there some way to shove variables into the "." namespace?  And if so (crossing my fingers) is there a way to merge namespaces in some way so that I can still access .Values and .Chart variables?

Answer (score 26):

Templates in helm cannot access variables.  However, the context handed to the template is a dictionary.  The sprig library is accessible from within the Go templates and can be used to manipulate dictionaries.

Take this simplified template:

```
{{- define "mytest" -}} 
  - name: mongod-{{ .index }}
{{- end -}}
```

You can now call this template as an example:

```
{{ range $index := until 5 }}
  {{- $p := dict "index" $index }}
  {{include "mytest" $p}}
{{- end -}}
```

This will output:

```
- name: mongod-0
- name: mongod-1
- name: mongod-2
- name: mongod-3
- name: mongod-4
```

You can also add items to an existing or the current scoped dictionary:

```
{{- $_ := set . "index" "none" }}
{{include "mytest" .}}
```

The $_ is used to suppress undesired output as "set" returns the new dictionary.  The above returns:

```
- name: mongod-none
```

Any values added to the dictionary will live beyond the call.  If you want to avoid polluting an existing dictionary you can force a deep copy with:

```
{{-  $d := merge (dict) . -}}
```

Anything added to "$d" will not exist in ".".

Comment: According to the current version(May 2018) of helm is this still the only way of passing variables to a template? @kscoder i tried to find other sources but did not find any information other than your post here.

Comment: A caveat that while this is a deep *merge*, it is not a deep copy. So if you modify items in $d that are inherited from ., the original . can be modified.

Comment: Where are functions like `set` and `merge` documented? I can't find them in https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/ or http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/.

Comment: @rcorre.  The documentation I use for sprig is here: http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/

Comment: ah, found it. It is under the dict functions: http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html

Answer (score 9):

I will left this here because some people might be trying to set a static value to a variable in Helm to re-use it in a template and they probably will find this SO question by its title. So, here is a trick:

**Update:**

There's a better way to do this:

```
{{- $_ := set . "appName" "app_name_one"-}}

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
metadata:
  name: {{ .appName }}
```

**The old advice (don't use it)**

Combined with the syntax from the answer above suggested by @kscoder

```
    ---
    # values.yml

    static_vars:
      app_name_one: app_name_one
      text_to_reuse: text_to_reuse

    ---    
    # templates/deployment.yml

    # now you don't need to copy-n-paste values, just set them here once
    {{- $text_to_reuse := index .Values "static_vars" "text_to_reuse" -}}
    {{- $app_name := index .Values "static_vars" "app_name_one" -}}
    {{- $_ := set . "app_name" $app_name -}}

    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Deployment
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
    metadata:
      name: {{ .app_name }}
    spec:
      selector:
        # https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/26202
        matchLabels:
          name: {{ .app_name }}
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            name: {{ .app_name }}
            name_alt: {{ $app_name }}
            other_label: {{ $text_to_reuse }}
    # and so on
```

Comment: Is there a way to define a global var which i could use in several templates? I want to randomize a string and reuse the same value upon several yaml files

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible (maybe). But I would recommend moving the logic to CI and pass the randomized string as a value.

Comment: if that string is reflected as an object (secret for example) - it can be done (as it creates it once, then we can reference it).
but indeed the only option right now is to move it to the CI